# Ruby Thread Pool abort_on_exception

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using Ruby's `Thread.pool` to manage ten threads for my program. I'm having two issues though:

1. I want to enable abort_on_exception for the pool. My relevant code is:

   ```
   pool = Thread.pool(thread_count)
   pool.abort_on_exception = true
   ```

   However I'm getting

   ```
   undefined method abort_on_exception= for #<Thread::Pool:0x007fb25bb144b8> (NoMethodError)
   ```

   when I run it. I've triple-checked and `abort_on_exception` is  supposed to be an attribute in `Thread.pool`. I'm using threads version 0.2.2.

Comment: I have answered your first question below. Please only ask one question per StackOverflow question. Thus, please edit your question, remove the second part and put it in a new one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abort_on_exception` method is defined on the `Thread::Pool` class itself, not on the individual instances. As such, you have to call

```
Thread::Pool.abort_on_exception = true
```

This method thus works very similar to [`Thread.abort_on_exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D) in the Ruby language core.